# To prevent Google Chrome Addons from starting webpages at 1st login?

Tags: google-chrome, usability

I have installed some addons. 
When I set my Google chrome in new computer, those addons always start new pages in new tabs. 
I would like to prevent this. 
Examples of such addons: *Checker Plus for Gmail*, *Turn Off the Lights*, *Webmail Ad Blocker*, ...

How can you prevent addons starting webpages at the first start of the browser as logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it not possible for you to simply remove the ad-ins or do you still want them all the add-ons are in:

**Setting -> More tools -> Extensions**

You can either remove it or disable any of them but you may need to restart chrome for it to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

One of the issue/feature is that example the "[Turn Off the Lights](http://www.turnoffthelights.com)" Chrome extension use local storage. This to save all your setting local on your computer. If you take a look inside this opensource browser extension.
https://github.com/turnoffthelights/Turn-Off-the-Lights-Chrome-extension
 You see most part is already converted to Chrome.storage API and possible soon all the other settings.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage
This "chrome.storage" feature can sync your the setting of the extension(s) you are using.

**How fix this?**

Well, ask the developer to update his code to "chrome.storage" API

Comment: It would be so great to have default settings where you can say that you do not want any addon affect new tabs in your browser. If any addon affects your preferences, they cannot be installed.

Comment: If the developer use this code, you sync all the Chrome extension settings to that computer. So the "new tab" page will be not visible (already saw that on your other computer with Google Chrome installed).

Comment: I did this one with several developers. They changed their procedures, but after a while, they changed back to their original procedures. It is simple to just delete such addons which initially are designed flawed, since there is no user control of the situation in Google Chrome.

Comment: "Turn Off the Lights" still got this Chrome storage on all his settings. What Chrome extensions developer didn't use this feature?

Comment: I think *Checker Plus for Gmail*. At least, its permissions were changed back and forth, once I contacted the developer.